# window.print() in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When I call `window.print()` in a iframe, the print out font-size is very small, but if I open the page in a new windows the font-size is regular. Is there any problem that may affect the font size when call `window.print()` in a iframe.

I also call `window.print()` in this way, but it still the same

```
var obiframe = parent.obnle.window;
obiframe.focus();
obiframe.print();
```

Comment: It could be caused by `media="print"` style, but hard to say without seeing some actual code.

Comment: hi Matt, i have not got any media="print" style

Comment: i use ie8 and firefox to test it. it have the same issue

Comment: Do you have "shrink to fit" turned on in your print options?

Comment: I'd guess you are using a different stylesheet in your iFrame with another font-size? Try to eliminate the CSS and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: actually it only happen in ie8, firefox is okay. i had eliminated the css, it still occurs

Comment: @Farray i don't know where to enable the "shrink to fit"

Comment: @Chris On any page, go to Print Preview and the Shrink-to-fit option should be clickable on one of the panes (I don't have IE8 any more so I can't remember exactly where it shows up).  Lemme' know...